# Image of linear mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

Let's observe transform function
$$A (z) = \frac{z-a}{\bar{a}z-1}$$
Where $a$ is complex constant and $|a| \neq 1$.

1. Find the inverse transform function:
   This is just straightforward calculation right?

\begin{align}
w=A (z) &= \frac{z-a}{\bar{a}z-1} \\
w(\bar{a}z-1)&=z-a \\
z=A^{-1}(w)&=\frac{w-a}{\bar{a} w -1}
\end{align}

2. determine unit circles image (range): This I have hard time, because I'm not really sure what is range... I have figured out that $|z|=1$ (unit circle) so
   \begin{align}
   |z|&=\bigg|\frac{w-a}{\bar{a} w -1} \bigg| \\
   |\bar{a} z -1|&=|z-a| \\
   |\bar{a} z -1|^2-|z-a|^2 &=0 \\
   \text{set $u=\bar{a} z -1=z-a$}& \\
   |u|^2-|u|^2&=0 \\
   u\bar{u}-u\bar{u}&=0 \\
   (\bar{a} z -1)(a \bar{z} -1)-(z-a)(\bar{z}-\bar{a})&=0 \\
   (a\bar{a} z \bar{z}-\bar{a} z-a \bar{z} +1)-(z\bar{z}-z \bar{a}-a \bar{z}+a\bar{a})&=0 \\
   |a|^2 |z|^2 +1 -|z|^2 - |a|^2&=0 \\
   (1-|z|^2)(1-|a|^2)&=0
   \end{align}
   And because $|a|\neq 1$ it must be that $|z|=1$

Comment: The first is right. Hint for the second: $\lvert \overline{a}z-1\rvert^2 - \lvert z-a\rvert^2$.

Comment: I don't get it. $|a| \neq 1$ so $a$ can't be 1.. but that's how the equation can hold.

Comment: If you compute the value of the expression I wrote, what do you get?

Comment: apparently it's $(|a|^2-1)(|w|^2-1)$ but I don't see how that expression manipulates to that one algebraly.

Comment: $z$, not $w$, but basically that. You know that $\lvert u\rvert^2 = u\overline{u}$, set $u = \overline{a}z-1$ resp. $u = z-a$ and compute. Once you have $\lvert \overline{a}z-1\rvert^2 - \lvert z-a\rvert^2 = (1-\lvert a\rvert^2)(1-\lvert z\rvert^2)$, you see that $\lvert z\rvert = 1 \iff \dotsc$, and you can see what happens to the unit circle.

Comment: I think I did the math correctly now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|\bar{a} \omega -1| =|\omega -a|\to |\bar{a} \omega -1|^2 =|\omega -a|^2 \to (|a|^2 -1)(|\omega |^2 -1)=0 \to |\omega |=1.$$

Comment: how do you go from $|\bar{a}w-1|^2=|w-a|^2 \to (|a|^2-1)(|w|^2-1)=0$. Like how do you construct that product

Comment: $|\bar{a} \omega -1|^2 =(\bar{a} \omega -1)\overline{(\bar{a} \omega -1)} =|a|^2 |\omega |^2 -\bar{a} \omega -\bar{\omega} a +1$ $|\omega -a|^2 =(\omega -a)\overline{(\omega -a)} =|\omega |^2 -\bar{a} \omega -\bar{\omega} a +|a|^2$ hence $|\omega |^2 |a|^2 -|a|^2 -|\omega|^2 +1=0$ hence $(|a|^2 -1)(|\omega|^2 -1)=0$